# Jquery Selector - Input [type="checkbox"] within class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Structure:

```
<ul class="week">
    <li class="on">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="MONDAY">
            <label for="MONDAY">Monday</label>
            <select name="time-from[MONDAY]">
```

i want to attach a click event on all input type checkbox within only the class "week".

requirements:

1. no intention to attach class to input
2. no use of slow :checkbox
3. no use of slow find() if possible

tried

```
$('.week [type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked') ){....
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Whats the problem? Could you post a fiddle - mine is working

Comment: `no use of slow find()` But `.find()` is faster in most cases

Comment: What is your issue? Are you binding event once element(s) available in the DOM? You have to replicate your issue so it can be check because currently, your question/issue doesn't make much sense

Comment: whats wrong with `$('.week [type="checkbox"]')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.week').on('click', "input[type='checkbox']", function(){    
    /*code*/   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('ul.week li div > input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
    // your code
   });
```